# In the Black Mirror episode "The National Anthem" why does Secretary Alex Cairns seem keen on making the PM agree to the the kidnapper's demand?

Tags: black-mirror, the-national-anthem

In the *Black Mirror* episode "The National Anthem" (S1E1), initially the PM refuses to meet the kidnappers demand. The kidnappers cut off Princess Suzanna's finger and he does not change his mind.

Cairns then talks to the PM about, how his refusal would paint a bad picture to the public and that they will not be able to protect the prime minister's family.

Why is she keen on having the PM agree to the demands and why does she tell him there is danger to his family?

Comment: But she was right, ti did help his image later even with divorce